# Where can I find MySQL Server name?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2010

I am new to MySQL, I am setting up a database connection to be used for a C# application. I am following a youtube tutorial on setting up this connection, but I am confused on what is a Server name? Is it just the IP Address or do I have to include the company domain name whos providing the server. Would the following be correct?

```
  private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "xxx.1x4.xxx.15x";
            database = "nameOfDatabase";
            uid = "username123";
            password = "pass123";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
                    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

           connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }
```

Comment: Depends entirely where the MySQL server is situated! Your obfuscated server var appears to suggest you have its IP address. Does that work?

Comment: @Matt yes I have the IP address, I am not sure if it works. I wanted to know what goes in the server field.

Comment: It can be an IP address, but it can also be an textual name, like "MyServer", or something. It's completely random; whatever the server was named when it was set up. Did you set up the server, or did someone else do it? If the latter, talk to that person.

Comment: Yes, it will be the IP address or hostname that resolves the server that hosts the database. The code looks OK - have you tried it and does it work?

Comment: @Melanie: I wouldn't say that was "*random*".

Comment: @Melanie Basically I have bought a domain name from a hosting company who also provide mysql database. I have created my database on their server. Now I just need to make a connection so I can extract the information from my database.

Comment: Then you need to ask them what the server name is, or use the IP address, if you have that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the ip adress along with the actual port for the mysql service will work unless security measures have been taken to prevent access.

example :  127.0.0.1:1840

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, you can use the IP address, although I've always used the hostname.

You might want to check out this question:
[Accessing SQL Server using an IP Address and Port Number ... Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630246/accessing-sql-server-using-an-ip-address-and-port-number-help)